# Decrease the number of AZs for a VPC using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC created using AWS CDK with the following config:

```
        const vpc = new cdk.aws_ec2.Vpc(this, `vpc-${ENV}`;, {
            maxAzs: 3,
            natGateways: 1,
            subnetConfiguration: [
                {
                    subnetType: cdk.aws_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
                },
                {
                    subnetType: cdk.aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
                },
                {
                    subnetType: cdk.aws_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
                }
            ]
        });
```

This is working fine for dev, prod, and staging infra (already deployed). However, we wish to update the development environment using the same stack but limiting the number of `maxAzs` to 1 as we do not require high availability (this should save on cost).

Doing this with:

```
... rest
    maxAzs: ENV === 'dev' ? 1 : 3,
...rest
```

When redeploying to update the dev env, I get the following error:

'''
xxx-stack failed: Error: The stack named xxx failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "The CIDR '...' conflicts with another subnet (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxx)"
'''

I presume this is due to the dev env already existing with 3 AZs and the resulting 9 subnets. Is it possible to decrease the amount of AZ's without destroying the stack completely and rebuilding?

Comment: Try modifying the CIDR at the same time to something non-overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not straightforward, because by default entire CIDR range will be equally divided between all subnets.

Imagine, for example, the following simplified scenario:
You have a VPC with CIDR range between `10.0.0.0` and `10.0.3.0`, with only 3 subnets in 3 AZs. You will end up having (roughly) following subnet IP ranges:

- Subnet 1: 10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.255
- Subnet 2: 10.0.0.1 - 10.0.1.255
- Subnet 3: 10.0.0.2 - 10.0.2.255

Note: I said `roughly` above, because in reality some IPs will be reserved, so distribution might not be exactly like above, but should be close.

Now, imagine that you change your CDK code to have only 1 subnet. This will result in generated CloudFormation code where a single subnet is assigned entire CIDR range. But keep in mind that when CloudFormation deployment happens it always follows pattern `create/updat resources -> cleanup old ones`, so it will try to update your first subnet **BEFORE** the other two are deleted. This will cause the CIDR range conflict you saw.

How can you fix this?

**Approach 1 (via code)**
One approach would be to make this change in two steps:

1. Delete the other two subnets, without changing first subnet's CIDR range. (Unfortunately, last I checked subnet's CIDR range was not visible in CDK L2 construct, so you might need to jump into [L1 construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnSubnet.html#cidrblock))
2. Once step 1 is deployed, remove the first subnet's CIDR range overwrite you added in step 1.

I haven't tried above steps myself, but in theory, after step 1, your two other subnets should be deleted, while subnet 1's CIDR range is not changed. This will then allow you to change subnet 1's CIDR range in second step. In your case you have several subnets in the first AZ, so you will need to overwrite CIDR ranges for all three of them

**Approach 2 (manual)**
You can also go into the console and manually delete the other subnets first, then try to deploy this change again. This is much simpler that the previous approach, but only works if you have permissions to perform destructive actions in your AWS console